# What causes those ACPI errors in Linux (and how to fix them)?

Tags: linux, laptop, linux-mint, operating-systems, hp

I installed Linux Mint 21 on my HP laptop. I got some errors I don't know how to solve. The first 2 days after installation, I had the following errors:

This is the error I was getting after I boot the system: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmfPH.jpg

This is the error that was appearing immediately after the first error shown in the above image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f86yJ.jpg

This is the error I was getting after I press the Power Off button and the system began to shut down: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6Vm0.jpg

The last error disappeared by itself; now the system doesn't show any messages when shutting down.

The following line:

```
[          0.163290] x86/cpu: VMX (outside TXT) disabled by BIOS
```

Was solved when I enabled the virtualization option in the BIOS: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouMyH.jpg

However, the rest of the errors remained unsolved:

```
[         0.232719] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\SB.OSC.CDW1], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
[         0.232848] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB._OSC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND)   (20210730/psparse-529)
```

Does anyone know how to solve those errors? I heard I need to change the ACPI option. The problem is that I don't have access to the advanced settings in the BIOS menu - **InsydeH20 Setup Utility**. And I don't know how to get access to the advanced settings menu (the ACPI options are inside the advanced settings menu).

Also, I will be thankful if someone explains to me what causes those errors. I didn't have such errors when i used Linux Mint 20.3 and when the kernel wasn't version 5 (or above). The problems started appearing in Linux Mint 21 and kernel 5 (and above).

Comment: You can ignore those errors. They're showing up with new kernels as you correctly observed because new kernels have new functions that aren't supported by older and even many brand new firmwares. A future firmware update may or may not no longer show them or show different ones instead. In a nutshell, don't stress.